# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0) with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know there are tons of questions with the above error message, but none seem to fix my issue. I have the below code that takes an azure queue and pulls event log entries from it and then saves them in an azure database using entity framework. The exception occurs on about 95% of the savechanges calls, but it's not on everyone of them. When the exception occurs the entity state is added and not modified and the key `EventLogEntryID` is 0 which some of the other stackoverflow answers suggest could be the issue. I'm disposing of the dbcontext after every save. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

```
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo)
    {

        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the queue client.
        queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        cloudqueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("events");
        if (!IsRunning)
        {
            int threads = 8;
            Task[] workers = new Task[threads];

            for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
            {
                Task task = new Task(() => WorkQueue());
                workers[i] = task;
                task.Start();
            }
            try
            {

                Task.WaitAll(workers);
                IsRunning = false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Proccess currently running");
        }

    }

    public static void WorkQueue()
    {
        var error = false;


        List<CloudQueueMessage> messagesList = new List<CloudQueueMessage>();
        List<EventLogEntry> entriesList = new List<EventLogEntry>();

        var messages = cloudqueue.GetMessages(32, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        while (messages != null)
        {

            foreach (CloudQueueMessage cloudQueueMessage in messages)
            {
                messagesList.Add(cloudQueueMessage);
                EventLogEntry entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventLogEntry>(cloudQueueMessage.AsString);
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var db = new EventContext())
                        {
                            db.Entries.Add(entry);
                            var result = db.SaveChanges() > 1;
                            if (result)
                            {
                                entriesList.Add(entry);
                                cloudqueue.DeleteMessage(cloudQueueMessage);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.Out.WriteLine("Entries not saved");
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        if (ex.InnerException != null)
                        {
                            if (ex.InnerException.InnerException != null)
                            {

                                var exception = ex.InnerException.InnerException as SqlException;
                                if (exception != null)
                                {
                                    if (exception.Number == 2601)
                                    {
                                        cloudqueue.DeleteMessage(cloudQueueMessage);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
                                        Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error number: {exception.Number}");
                                        error = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
            Console.Out.WriteLine($"{entriesList.Count} entries added");
            Console.Out.WriteLine($"{messagesList.Count} messages pulled");

            entriesList = new List<EventLogEntry>();
            messagesList = new List<CloudQueueMessage>();
            messages = !error ? cloudqueue.GetMessages(32, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)) : null;
        }
    }


public class EventLogData
{
    [Key]
    public int EventLogDataID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

}

public class EventLogEntry
{
    [Key]
    public int EventLogEntryID { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_CompanyID", IsClustered = false)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_EventID", IsClustered = false)]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public string Opcode { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_TimeCreatedEventRecordIDComputer", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_TimeCreatedEventRecordIDComputer", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string EventRecordID { get; set; }
    public string Correlation { get; set; }
    public string Channel { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_TimeCreatedEventRecordIDComputer", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Computer { get; set; }
    public string Security { get; set; }
    public string TargetLogonId { get; set; }
    public string SubjectLogonId { get; set; }
    public string HandleID { get; set; }
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
    public string AccessList { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_SubjectUserName", IsClustered = false)]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string SubjectUserName { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_LogonType", IsClustered = false)]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string LogonType { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_TargetUserName", IsClustered = false)]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string TargetUserName { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_IsDelete", IsClustered = false)]
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EventLogData> EventData { get; set; }

    public EventLogEntry()
    {
        EventData = new List<EventLogData>();
    }
}

class EventContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EventLogEntry> Entries { get; set; }

    public EventContext():base("name=EventContext")
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any triggers on the target table?

Comment: There are no triggers on any of the tables.

Comment: Can you use EF Logging or SQL Profiler or IntelliTrace to see the database traffic?

Comment: I used EF Logging to log out to the console but didn't see anything that stood out to me, but also I'm not 100% sure what would have been of value and what wouldn't have. This is the only application that writes to or updates the database.

Comment: Can you create a small, self-contained repro with one of your incoming JSON messages?

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: In the question.  Single file console application pasted into the body of your question, if you get a repro.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150843/discussion-between-user3064073-and-david-browne-microsoft).